# I have an issue with an UIAlertView showing repeatedly can't find the source

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uialertview

My problem is this, in the app when a user clicks somewhere not important an alertView is raised that's ok, I can find the call to that view, but then is showing again and again empty and I have placed breakpoint everywhere I see a call to any alert. But the ghost alert is not breaking anywhere I have no idea who is throwing it is just a sentient view.

Can you give some tips on how to pin point where is the view being called?

[image: Phantom alertView]

[image: Breakpoint never hitting that alert]

EDIT:

Code for the viewController:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "FormViewController.h"
#import "FormPageViewController.h"
#import "FormElement+UtilityMethods.h"
#import "UserBO.h"
#import "RecordBO.h"
#import "RecordAnswer.h"
#import "UserDefaultsUtilities.h"
#import "TimeTrackingUtilities.h"
#import "DxColors.h"
#import "EDQueueUtilities.h"
#import "GroupAnswerMetadata.h"
#import "RecordAnswer+UtilityMethods.h"
#import "Record+UtilityMethods.h"
#import "FormPageIndexViewController.h"
#import "ManagedObjectUtilities.h"
#import "EDQueue.h"
#import "EDQueueUtilities.h"
#import "DxAnswerObject.h"
#import "ImageAnswerMetadata.h"

#import "DateUtilities.h"
#import <ifaddrs.h>
#import "CarbonKit.h"

#define INITIAL_CONTROLLER_INDEX 0
#define FORM_RECORDS_TEMP_NAME @"<~TMP>"

#define TAG_RETURN_BUTTON 0
#define TAG_SAVE_BUTTON 1
#define TAG_SEND_BUTTON 2

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, AlertViewPurpose) {
    ALERT_VIEW_FORM_NONE                = 0,
    ALERT_VIEW_FORM_SEND_SUCCESS        = 1,
    ALERT_VIEW_FORM_SEND_FAILURE        = 2,
    ALERT_VIEW_FORM_SAVE_PROMPT         = 3,
    ALERT_VIEW_FORM_FILE_NAME_PROMPT    = 4,
    ALERT_VIEW_FORM_ASYNC_SEND_SUCCESS  = 5,
    ALERT_VIEW_FORM_COULDNT_SEND        = 6,
    ALERT_VIEW_FORM_WANT_TO_SEND        = 7,
    ALERT_VIEW_FORM_SAVE_IN_CONTEXT_PROMPT = 8,
    ALERT_VIEW_FORM_FILE_NAME_IN_CTXT_SAVE_PROMPT = 9,
    ALERT_VIEW_FORM_REQUIRED_INTERNET_CONECTION = 10,
    // Enumeration counter.
    ALERT_VIEW_PURPOSE_COUNT
};

// Based on:
// Ref.: http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

@interface FormViewController () <RecordBOProtocol, FieldElementProtocol,
CLLocationManagerDelegate, FormPageIndexProtocol,CarbonTabSwipeNavigationDelegate>
{
    AlertViewPurpose _currentAlertViewPurpose;
    CarbonTabSwipeNavigation *_carbonTabSwipeNavigation;
    BOOL _unedited;
    BOOL _formRecordNilAtStartUp;
    BOOL _timestampTaken;

    CLLocationManager *_locationManager;
    CLLocation *_location;
    NSDate *_timeSpentBaseTimestamp;
    NSArray *_sortedPages;
    NSUInteger _currentPageIndex;
    NSString *formID;
    NSArray *_pagesNames;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblFormTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnSmallReturn;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnSmallSave;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnSmallSend;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnBigSend;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *btnReturn;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *lblBack;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *lblSave;


@end

@implementation FormViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        _currentAlertViewPurpose = ALERT_VIEW_FORM_NONE;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self localizedButtons];

    // Starting up location manager if form requires it.
    // Ref.:
    // https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/requestAlwaysAuthorization
    if ([self.form.geolocationEnabled boolValue]) {

        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        _locationManager.delegate = self;

        if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {

            CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

            if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
                // Requesting authorization.
                if ([CLLocationManager instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
#ifdef DEBUG_MODE
                    NSAssert(
                             [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] valueForKey:@"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription"],
                             @"For iOS 8 and above, your app must have a value for NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in its Info.plist");
#endif // DEBUG_MODE
                    [_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
                }
            } else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways ||
                       status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
                _locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
                _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
                [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
            }
        }
    }

    self.lblFormTitle.text = self.form.name ;

    // Saving whether self.formRecord was nil at beginning.
    // Important for time spent tap calculations.
    _formRecordNilAtStartUp = self.formRecord == nil;

    [self setup];

    //Take the time for counting 
    _timeSpentBaseTimestamp = [NSDate date];

    _unedited = YES;
}

-(void)localizedButtons
{
    [self.lblBack setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Back", @"Regresar") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.lblSave setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Save", @"Guardar") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.btnBigSend setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Send", @"Enviar") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// Overriding from DxBaseViewController.
-(void)refresh
{
}

-(void)setup
{
    // Obtaining sorted pages array.
    _sortedPages = [[self.form.pages allObjects]
                    sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Page *obj1, Page * obj2) {
                        return [obj1.pageNumber compare: obj2.pageNumber];
                    }];
    //Adding toolBar
    NSMutableArray *namesPages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (Page *page in _sortedPages) {
        NSString *namePage = page.name;
        [namesPages addObject:namePage];
    }
    _pagesNames = [namesPages copy] ;

    // Creating by default a record in case there's none.
    if (self.formRecord == nil) {
        self.formRecord = [Record createInContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        // Filling in basic record information.
        self.formRecord.name = FORM_RECORDS_TEMP_NAME;
        self.formRecord.editable = self.form.editableRecords;
        self.formRecord.dateLastSaved = self.formRecord.dateCreated = [NSDate date];
        self.formRecord.syncStatusId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:SYNC_STATUS_NOT_SYNCED];
        self.formRecord.user = [UserBO loggedInUser];
        self.formRecord.form = self.form;
        self.formRecord.formId = self.form.pkey;
        self.formRecord.temporary = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
        self.formRecord.isBeingEdited = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
        // Committing record information as is. It will be removed if user doesn't
        // want to save changes.
        if (![Record commitChangesFromContext:self.managedObjectContext]) {
            DebugLog(@"Temp form record couldn't be saved! Check!");
        }



        // Initializing page view controller.
        _carbonTabSwipeNavigation =[[CarbonTabSwipeNavigation alloc] initWithItems:_pagesNames
                                                                          delegate:self];
        _carbonTabSwipeNavigation.toolbar.barTintColor = [DxColors colorWithHexRGB:NEW_FORMS_GREEN];
        [_carbonTabSwipeNavigation setNormalColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [_carbonTabSwipeNavigation setIndicatorColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [_carbonTabSwipeNavigation setSelectedColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    } else {
        [self prepareControllerForEdition];
    }

    [_carbonTabSwipeNavigation insertIntoRootViewController:self];

    self.pageViewController = _carbonTabSwipeNavigation.pageViewController;
}

- (UIViewController *)carbonTabSwipeNavigation:(CarbonTabSwipeNavigation *)carbontTabSwipeNavigation
                         viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    _currentPageIndex = index;
    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    FormPageViewController *formPageViewController = [[FormPageViewController alloc] init];
    formPageViewController.pageIndex = index;
    formPageViewController.formPage = _sortedPages[index];
    formPageViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    formPageViewController.formRecord = self.formRecord;
    formPageViewController.observer = self;


    formPageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                                                   0,
                                                   self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                   self.view.frame.size.height);

    return formPageViewController;
}

#pragma mark - Button Actions (IBActions)

-(IBAction)send:(id)sender
{
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(isAlertViewShowing:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];

    [self setButtonWithTag:self.btnBigSend.tag toHighlight:NO];

    // Disabling button to avoid double submissions.
    self.btnBigSend.enabled = NO;

    // Show alert.
    [self showAreYouReadyToSubmitFormMsg];

}
```

... can't paste it all

Comment: Try setting a symbolic breakpoint for the `UIAlertView show` method.

Comment: Could you explain that? How?

Comment: Tap the + in the bottom left of the breakpoint list. Choose to add a symbolic breakpoint. Enter the symbol `-[UIAlertView show]`.

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: @Pedro.Alonso, it might be a `UIAlertController` as well. Could you try setting a symbolic breakpoint on `[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:message:preferredStyle:]`?

Comment: @Pedro.Alonso, or even on `[UIAlertController alloc]` for that matter.

Comment: @Lion I don't have I post the view code but I don't think this is where the call is being made, hold on, see edit.

Comment: @rmaddy That made it break, thanks a lot if you can put it as an answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

For testing only:

Subclass `UIAlertView` i.e. `@interface MyAlertView : UIAlertView`

Then replace all instances of `UIAlertView` from `MyAlertView` 
i.e. `MyAlertView *someAlert = [[MyAlertView alloc] init.......];`

Then override

```
-(void)show {

[super show];

//Your breakpoint here

OR

NSLog([NSThread callStackSymbols]);
}
```

Comment: I got it t break, thanks for you suggestion I have now to fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

Check your viewcontroller that has an uialertviewdelegate.

1. Log your alertview.delegate
2. Check your super class of a viewcontroller that it doesn't call uialertviewdelegate function.
3. If it is an UIAlertController, check viewwillappear, viewdidappear, viewwilldisappear (super class too) and find out they don't call [alertview show]

Comment: Just the one I'm getting that on? Or all the ones that  are delegates?

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the content of your AlertView, if it has no content at all, don't present it!

To do this check the message you are passing to the method that presents the alertView.

However, I can't seem to find your method `showAreYouReadyToSubmitFormMsg`.

Comment: That sounds interesting. How can I capture it? if I don't know where is being called?

Answer (score 1):

Why you take enum for alertview ? just make instance of `UIAlertView` where it require's to show. you can make one method in which you can pass two string parameters alertview massage and title and method shows alertview with this title and massage.

Comment: Is not my code I have inherited and is working ok for the most part there are just a few tiny issue here and there :)